# How to access object instance from anonymous function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am dealing with the following situation.

I have to use a method from the class, but I have to call a callback too...
Look at the code, I have created the `_this` var because I don't know how to access the `DeviceAnalyzer` instance from inside the anonymous function...

Is there another way? I think the way I did it is kind of nasty haha

```
DeviceAnalyzer.prototype.pingProcess = function(deviceInfo, callback) {
    var _this = this;
    netutils.ping(host.ipAddress, function(isAlive) {
        deviceInfo.isAlive = isAlive
        _this.emit('device', deviceInfo);
        callback(null, deviceInfo);
    });
};
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with it. I usually do something similar, like "var self = this;"

Comment: code looks good. No need of over complicating the code just to access `this`. This code is legible and yields the result same as other solutions.

Comment: You have three other options : ``apply``,``call`` or  ``bind`` just pick one.

Comment: The answer from magnudae seams to be cleaner!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With ES6 and anonymous function you do not have to set this or bind it.

```
DeviceAnalyzer.prototype.pingProcess = function(deviceInfo, callback)    {
  netutils.ping(host.ipAddress, (isAlive) => {
      deviceInfo.isAlive = isAlive
      this.emit('device', deviceInfo);
      callback(null, deviceInfo);
  });
};
```

Comment: I think this is the best solution

Comment: Remember that you can not run ES6 directly in every browser. This means  you have to transpile it to ES5, but ES6 contains so much niceness its worth it =)

Answer (score 1):

With [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)

```
DeviceAnalyzer.prototype.pingProcess = function(deviceInfo, callback) {
    (function (that) {
      return netutils.ping(host.ipAddress, function(isAlive) {
        deviceInfo.isAlive = isAlive
        that.emit('device', deviceInfo);
        callback(null, deviceInfo);
    }))(this);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The above approach is fine.

An alternative would be to use [**bind**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

```
DeviceAnalyzer.prototype.pingProcess = function(deviceInfo, callback) {
    netutils.ping(host.ipAddress, function(isAlive) {
        deviceInfo.isAlive = isAlive
        this.emit('device', deviceInfo);
        callback(null, deviceInfo);
    }.bind(this));
};
```

Comment: Don't you think you are overriding the `this`. What if `netutils.ping` is sending some objects/function by binding to `this` to the callback like consider `this.event` sent on click events callbacks in jquery.

Comment: @Nirus, absolutely, in that case, this would not be the optimal solution